# Is there any equivalent to Marshal in c# to Java?

Tags: java, c#, marshalling, intptr

Is there any Native Android Java/Kotlin equivalent to C#'s `IntPtr` and `Marshall`?

```
IntPtr unmanagedMemory = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
Marshal.Copy(source, sourceIndex, unmanagedMemory, length);
object returnValue = Marshal.PtrToStructure(unmanagedMemory, destinationType);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedMemory);
```

Comment: [`sun.misc.Unsafe`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html) has methods that do things like that. I don't know if it's available in Android though.

Comment: I don't know, but does [GraalVM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/graalvm/enterprise/21/sdk/index.html?org/graalvm/nativeimage/UnmanagedMemory.html) help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way to do this with Android. Even in my personal experience I tried with sun.misc.Unsafe, but that does not even helped me.